# Craigslist monitoring and notification

Tags: notifications, craigslist

I have setup Google Reader with an RSS feed to some specific Craig's List searches so that I can try to get new postings for items I'm looking for quickly. There's two problems with this:

1. Google Reader seems to have a bit of a delay in getting the new postings;
2. I have to go to Google Reader to see them.

Is there a way to get new postings emailed to me as soon as they are posted?

Answer (score 2):

You could burn an RSS feed in Feedburner and subscribe via e-mail.

You're probably still going to see a delay, though, as well-behaved feed aggregators won't poll a feed more than once an hour or so.

Comment: Thanks. It's too slow that way. I'm looking for as close to real-time as possible.

Comment: Then RSS may not be your solution, unless you're going to roll your own. But then if you're polling too often they're likely to cut you off.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will need a custom solution (perl script, C#, etc) then. Or maybe create an iMacros macro that searches the site in a loop and looks for changes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [CraigsHunter](http://www.craigshunter.com) - Craigslist notifications plugin for Chrome. Much easier then RSS feeds.

Answer (score 0):

Try the CLmonitor app for Android phones; works really well. I use it all the time.

You can download it here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.clmonitor

Comment: Are you affiliated with the publishers of this app? If so, you should disclose it.

Comment: Not affiliated ... just a user.

Comment: @vidar Why are you asking this question.. do you see an affiliate id in the url??

Comment: No. But answers containing not much more than a link, from a user with 1 reputation, are often automated spam messages. But @Paul says he's not affiliated with the publishers, and that's fine with me.